# Name of the cut-outs in the side of a printed dictionary at each letter

Tags: single-word-requests

Paper dictionaries often have cut-outs in the pages that make it easier to turn to (words beginning with) each letter.  Here's a picture:

[image: Dictionary with notched edge]

I know there's a name for these things but I can't remember what it is and it's remarkably hard to search for information *about* dictionaries — the search engines insist on bringing up dictionary definitions of the keywords you try.  Anyone know the word?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**[Index Notches](https://books.google.com/books?id=peEDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA184&lpg=PA184&dq="index+notches"+in+reference+books&source=bl&ots=GAMag_Af2g&sig=DKe-3vANJrr907E3rGaRmpEZE14&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMqd_lvMLUAhUIWj4KHQrqCxgQ6AEINTAD#v=onepage&q=%22index%20notches%22%20in%20reference%20books&f=false)**.

[image: How to make Index Notches]

And [here's a patent](http://www.freepatentsonline.com/5216961.pdf) for a device to cut index notches.

Comment: The book you linked to is full of gems!

Comment: I selected this answer over the other one, even though ["thumb index" is much more frequently used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thumb+notch%2Cindex+notch%2Cthumb+tab%2Cthumb+index%2Cthumb+cut&year_start=1880&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthumb%20notch%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cindex%20notch%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthumb%20tab%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthumb%20index%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthumb%20cut%3B%2Cc0), because I wanted the term for an individual notch, not for the whole set.

Comment: It *never occurred to me* that I could do this myself with my own notebooks. (There must be a word for this mental state...)

Answer (score 43):

Wikipedia calls this a [**thumb index**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thumb_index). It is also frequently used with bibles for quickly finding each book.

EDIT: To clarify, this refers to the whole set of notches. The individual notches can be called *thumb tabs* (as given by [Chris H](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/48571/chris-h) in the comments), *index notches* (as given in [Davo's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/394253/240429)), or [*thumb notches*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thumb%20notch).

Comment: Also "thumb tabs" for the notches themselves.

Comment: @ChrisH Wouldn't "thumb tabs" be something that sticks out?  Those exist too, but ...

Comment: @zwol I know what you mean, but I confirmed my recollection (Bibles in Sunday School) with a quick [google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q="thumb+tabs"+-guitar) (you have to exclude "guitar").

Comment: Thanks @ChrisH, I've edited that into my answer, I hope that's ok with you?

Comment: @SteveES of course

Comment: Minor quibble, but in a Bible the notches/tabs mark the start of each _book_, not each _chapter_ - there are nearly 1200 chapters, that'd be a lot of notches!

Comment: @talrnu You're right, I'll change it!

Comment: I think this is the correct answer.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova I wanted the term for an individual notch, not the whole set.

Answer (score -1):

For the want of a special word I would call them "tabs'. To distinguish them from the tabs on files perhaps we could name them as "index tabs".

Comment: Definitely NOT 'Tabs' Reason: Tabs 'stick out' and that name is used in so many different areas, each meaning something that sticks out. In Organ Technology, for instance, many modern consoles (keyboards) have 'Tab' stops - they stick out. So the cut-away indexing in a dictionary or Bible is simply that - it's cut away and reveals the letter at the beginning of a section or, Bible - it's cut away to reveal the name of one of the Books at its beginning.